# How to redirect .com.sg to .sg in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, redirect

I was using Firebase Hosting, but recently our team decided to change to GAE.

After we added two custom domains, we need to redirect `.com.sg` to `.sg` always.

Does anyone know how to achieve this feature?

Am using Nodejs as server language. Any help will be appreciated very much! Cheers